# How can I fix this Firestore error: FieldPath.documentId is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My function pulls from 2 firestore Collections: Media, and Users. Inside Users is a subcollection with a list of all of their movies. Media contains the movies' details. I want my function to grab all movies in their 'MediaList', access the media_uid field inside of the document, and use this to access all Media with matching media_uid.

What I have tried:

1. verified that i imported FieldPath correctly:

```
import { getDocs, collection, getDoc, setDoc, addDoc, updateDoc, doc, where, query, writeBatch, FieldPath } from "firebase/firestore"
```

2. verified that all media_uid's are also in the Media Collection

here is the specific code which is causing the error:

```
const mediaQuery = query(mediaRef, where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', media_ids));
```

and here is the full function:

```
export const getUserMedia = async (uid) => {
    try {
        const userDocRef = doc(db, 'Users', uid);
        const mediaListCollectionRef = collection(userDocRef, 'MediaList');
        const mediaListSnapshot = await getDocs(mediaListCollectionRef);
        const userData = mediaListSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), key: doc.id }));

        // Get the document IDs directly from the MediaList collection
        const media_ids = mediaListSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.id);
        console.log('media_ids:', media_ids);

        const mediaRef = collection(db, 'Media');

        // Use where-in query to fetch only documents with specified document IDs
        const mediaQuery = query(mediaRef, where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', media_ids));
        const mediaSnapshots = await getDocs(mediaQuery);
        console.log('mediaSnapshots:', mediaSnapshots.docs);

        const combinedData = mediaSnapshots.docs.map((docSnapshot, index) => {
            const mediaData = docSnapshot.exists() ? docSnapshot.data() : null;
            return mediaData ? { ...mediaData, ...userData[index] } : null;
        });

        console.log('combinedData:', combinedData);

        // return combinedData.filter((data) => data !== null);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

resulting error:

> TypeError: firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.FieldPath.documentId is not a function

Comment: Instead of just saying that you imported FieldPath correctly, you should show the actual code.  On Stack Overflow, it's important that you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) of the code that doesn't work the way you expect so that anyone can copy and reproduce the same.  Please edit the question to be complete.

Comment: The way you are merging `userData` and `mediaSnapshots` is incorrect. The order of documents returned from the server will not necessarily be in the same order as your incoming argument and some may not even be present if they don't exist. To get a merged array properly, you should create requests for each document: `await Promise.all(docIds.map(id => getDoc(doc(parentColRef, id)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to the ID of a document, you should use the `documentId` method from the firebase modular sdk.

```
import { documentId } from 'firebase/firestore'

const mediaQuery = query(mediaRef, where(documentId(), 'in', media_ids));
```

Comment: @mushroomsstudent Do you get a result when you use `getDoc` and `doc` for each document 1 by 1? Is a security rule blocking the read? Are there more than 10 items in `media_ids`? ('in' operators are limited to an array size of 10)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using webpack. Are you building for frontend client?

According to the docs, there's no `documentId` method in `FieldPath`.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.fieldpath

You might be looking at the server library reference, which is not suitable to use on the frontend.

Comment: Yes I'm building using Nextjs13/Nodejs. I was referencing https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldPath is this the server library?